# 2sxc 11 LTS (11.07.0X)/Timeline JS > parsererror

Tags: 2sxc

After Upgrade 2sxc from 1106.01 to 11.07.00/11.07.01 the Timeline JS give me errors.
I seen the same on your website:
https://2sxc.org/dnn-app-demos/en/Apps/Timeline-JS > error showing content

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow.

I'm not sure if we're talking about the same error. The error you mentioned on that page actually was another module which should have shown more internal information. But the timeline itself is working as expected:
[image]

BTW: I know we did fix something minor in 11.07.02 which had to do with this, maybe that's the difference. Best give that a ride and then post follow up question or mark as solved.

Comment: Hi Daniel
Thank you for your message. Yes, the problem has improved with the last version 07/11/02. Thank you very much from my side.
I just haven't found the switch in German in the timeline. Date is still in English ;)